# How to run Three different websites in single Django project

Tags: python, django

I want to run Three websites in single Django project...

`Site_1,Site_2,Site_3` has same `models.py`,same views.py and same urls.py file..
But different `sqlite.db` file..different template Dir.will it be possible to run sites under this scenario

Comment: please take a look at `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/` may be it will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your scenario...I have included a flag variable to `settings.py` you can set `flag` values to `1,2 or 3` and based on the `flag` values you can then load `templates and static DIR`...then you can use same `views.py,urls.py,models.py`....but make sure you use the app's DB file for the all three websites but name can be changed....as it is app's specific and if you use another app's DB file you will get error...Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks i am trying you solution.

Comment: Thanks i tried your solution and it worked and thanks for the tip...that error did occurred ....